# JavaScript listener not triggering onClick TamperMonkey

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, listener

I am fairly new to JavaScript but have quite a lot of experience with Java so I began to try to work on a script / bot plugin for a website. However, it seems like the listener I've created for the startButton is not triggering with the proper onClick.

The script is being run inside of TamperMonkey (this is why the HTML insert is on a single line and why === instead of ==).

I've checked all the id's and the regular logic behind it, and the listener should work, however it's giving no indication as such. I have it mainly set so that other things would be disabled so I would know the startButton worked, however nothing is happening. When I click the stopButton, it gives the regular alert of "Already stopped...". The code for all the relevant areas can be found here: http://pastebin.com/0qJ1Hvz0

I have been looking around and can't seem to find a related issue. I will continue to search in the mean time. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
document.getElementById('startButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
  alert('do something');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After drilling through your codes:

There was no HTML div with class `progress` so I inserted one (the parent)

Your div that has id  `stopAfterXGamesCheckbox` in fact your html id was  stopA**F**terXGamesCheckbox

There was a label for  `stopAfterXGamesCheckbox` but no div with an id for that..so swimming in the ocean I applied one to see what happens
Also, try not to put `label for=""` as an HTML tag.

there was a label with that like `label for = stopAfterReachingXCheckbox`;
This raised an error . I believe it should be `label id = stopAfterReachingXCheckbox`

finally  snippet below

```js
    // INSERTING UI INTO WEBPAGE
    var UI_html = '<style scoped> @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:300); table { font-family: "Ubuntu", sans-serif; background-color: #404040; color: #4A77A4; } #header { background-color: #262626; color: #ff0066; } label { font-weight: normal; } .odds { font-weight: normal; color: #00ffcc; } input[type=text] { border-radius: 5px; border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .25); color: #808080; background-color: #262626; } input[type=text]:focus { background-color: #4A77A4; color: #ffcc00; } input[type=button] { background-color: #262626; border-color: #1a1a1a; } #startButton { color: #2ecc71; } #stopButton { color: #e74c3c; }</style><hr /><table border="1"><tbody><tr id="header"><td><input checked="checked" name="system" type="radio" value="nightengale" /> <label for="nightengaleRadioBtn">=]</label></td></tr><tr><td><table><tbody><tr><td><label for="defaultBetInput">Default Bet: </label> <input type="text" id="defaultBetInput"/></td></tr><tr><td><input type="checkbox" id="stopAfterXGamesCheckbox"/> <label >Stop after <input type="text" id="stopAfterXGamesInput"/> games</label></td></tr><tr><td><input type="checkbox" /> <label id="stopAfterReachingXCheckbox">Stop after reaching <input type="text" id="stopAfterReachingXInput"/> </label></td></tr><tr><td><label for="currentBalance">Current Balance: </label><span id="currentBalanceText"> -- </span></td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr><tr><td><input style="width: 50%;" type="button" value="Start" id="startButton"/><input style="width: 50%;" type="button" value="Stop" id="stopButton"/></td></tr></tbody></table><hr />';
    var UI = document.createElement('div');
    UI.innerHTML = UI_html;
    var insertBefore = document.getElementsByClassName("progress")[0];
    insertBefore.parentNode.insertBefore(UI, insertBefore);
    // FINISHED INSERTING UI INTO WEBPAGE
    // DEFINING VARIABLES
    var statusBanner = document.getElementById("banner");
    var redBetButton = document.getElementsByClassName("betButton")[0];
    var greenBetButton = document.getElementsByClassName("betButton")[1];
    var blackBetButton = document.getElementsByClassName("betButton")[2];
    var balanceSpan = document.getElementById("balance_r");
    var balanceSpanUI = document.getElementById("currentBalanceText");
    var betAmountInput = document.getElementById("betAmount");
   
    var defaultBetInput = document.getElementById("defaultBetInput");
    
    var stopAfterXGamesCheckbox = document.getElementById("stopAfterXGamesCheckbox");
    console.log(stopAfterXGamesCheckbox,defaultBetInput);
    var stopAfterXCheckbox = document.getElementById("stopAfterReachingXCheckbox");
    var stopAfterXGamesInput = document.getElementById("stopAfterXGamesInput");
    var stopAfterXInput = document.getElementById("stopAfterReachingXInput");
   
    var running = false;
    // FINISHED DEFINING VARIABLES
    // DEFINING LISTENERS (FOR UI)
    startButton.onclick = function()
    {
        var passedTest = true;
        if (defaultBetInput.value === '' || defaultBetInput.value <= 0)
            passedTest = false;
        if (stopAfterXGamesCheckbox.checked && (stopAfterXGamesInput.value === '' || stopAfterXGamesInput.value <= 0))
            passedTest = false;
        if (stopAfterXCheckbox.checked && (stopAfterXInput.value === '' || stopAfterXInput.value <= 0))
            passedTest = false;
       
        if (!running && passedTest)
        {
            running = true;
            defaultBetInput.disabled = true;
            stopAfterXGamesCheckbox.disabled = true;
            stopAfterXGamesInput.disabled = true;
            stopAfterXCheckbox.disabled = true;
            stopAfterXInput.disabled = true;
           
          //  balanceSpanUI.innerHTML = getBalance();
        } else if (!passedTest) {
            alert("Either uncheck the boxes, or fill in the associated fields.");
        } else {
            alert("Already running...");
        }
    };
   
    stopButton.onclick = function()
    {
        if (running)
        {
            running = false;
            defaultBetInput.disabled = false;
            stopAfterXGamesCheckbox.disabled = false;
            stopAfterXGamesInput.disabled = false;
            stopAfterXCheckbox.disabled = false;
            stopAfterXInput.disabled = false;
           
            balanceSpanUI.innerHTML = "--";
        } else {
            alert("Already stopped...");
        }
    };
   
    defaultBetInput.oninput = function()
    {
       
    };
    // FINISHED DEFINING LISTENERS (FOR UI)
    // DEFINING FUNCTIONS
    function getBalance()
    {
        return balanceSpan.innerHTML;
    }
```

```html
<div class="progress">
</div>
```